# How do I set an Integer in a UITextfield using Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data, uitextfield, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I can set text in my managed object like this...

```
[editedObject setValue:textField.text forKey:editedFieldKey];
```

but I can't set this...

```
[editedObject setValue:numberField.text forKey:editedFieldKey];
```

In the XCode Template I can set this straight into the Managed Object but like this...

```
setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:200] forKey:@"jCode"];
```

but I can't seem to set it via a UITextField...  Please can someone point me in the right direction...  It will be highly appriciated...

Answer (score 9):

You likely don't want to create an instance variable in the header. You can simplify your implementation and provide an `(id)value` all in one line.

```
[editedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[numberField text] integerValue]] forKey:editedFieldKey];
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this helped me and seemed to help @Stef. Not sure why he didn't accept this as the right answer though. :/

Answer (score 1):

Thanx Eminatas...

1st what I did is in my header file add an int..

```
int userNumber;
```

Then in my implimentation, added this

```
NSString *numberString = [numberField text];
userNumber = [numberString intValue];
```

Then edited up managedObject like this...

```
[editedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:userNumber] forKey:editedFieldKey];
```

Thanx for pointing me in the right direction...

Stef :-)

Answer (score 0):

use `[numberField integerValue]` to get integer from textfield.